# How can I remove element in array value using filter javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to delete all element getData  because It always same value. I try to use filter method to remove them

Here is my data

```
let data = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "employee_id": 2290,
        "getData": {
            "id": 9070
        },
    },
     {
        "id": 4,
        "employee_id": 2291,
        "getData": {
            "id": 9070
        },
    }
]
```

Here is what I do

```
data =  data.filter(item => {
            return item.getData != null;
        });
```

Here is what I want

```
let data = [
  {
      "id": 3,
      "employee_id": 2290,
  },
   {
      "id": 4,
      "employee_id": 2291,

  }
]
```

Is filter is the best way to remove this if not please give me some advice thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter is used to filter out items from an array the more suited ways for doing what you want to achieve is [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Below is a demo that can help you.

Also to remove a property form an object use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator

```js
let data = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "employee_id": 2290,
        "getData": {
            "id": 9070
        },
    },
     {
        "id": 4,
        "employee_id": 2291,
        "getData": {
            "id": 9070
        },
    }
]

data.map((item)=>{delete item.getData});
console.log(data);

let data2 = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "employee_id": 2290,
        "getData": {
            "id": 9070
        },
    },
     {
        "id": 4,
        "employee_id": 2291,
        "getData": {
            "id": 9070
        },
    }
]

data2.forEach((item)=>{delete item.getData});
console.log(data);
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: oh thanks that's why people down vote my question I miss understand about filter haha sorry thank you I will mark this after 5 min

Comment: @Ach thats OK it happens with everyone... Glad could help.. Also you can mark this as the accepted answer if you find it correct..

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data,function(i,e){delete data[i]["getData"];})
```

OR

```
$.grep(data,function(e,i){delete data[i]["getData"];})
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter is to remove items from an array, not to remove properties from an object inside an array. You should use the map function.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "employee_id": 2290,
        "getData": {
            "id": 9070
        },
    },
     {
        "id": 4,
        "employee_id": 2291,
        "getData": {
            "id": 9070
        },
    }
]

let output = data.map(({id, employee_id}) => ({ id, employee_id }));

console.log(output)
```